# Unknown types error over WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to use this method on WCF client:

```
public interface IOhmioService
{        
  [OperationContract]
  IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(Type type);       
}

public class OhmioService : IOhmioService
{
  public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(Type type)
  {
     var _obj = (IEnumerador)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     return _obj.Enumerar();  
  }
}
```

and Implemented like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(Type type)
    {
        dynamic _obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return (IEnumerable<Enumerador>)_obj.Enumerar();
    }
```

And it gives me error because of unknown types, but i can't understand why. The return type is known by server and client.I'm only trying to tell from client wich kind of object to create. I'm sure that if I pass the Type parameter as a string for instance and use a select case it will work without problems.
Is there another way to do generic methods on WCF service? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the error i get:

> Type 'System.RuntimeType' wasn't spected with the contract name RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'. Trye to use DataContractResolver or add the unknown types staticaly to the list of known types (for instance, using the attribute KnownTypeAttribute or adding them to the list of known types to pass to DataContractSerializer)

Comment: I guess its not possible. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods

Comment: Thanks @qamar. I understand that i cannot return a generic type. But in this case my return type is known, and the parameter type is also known, so what i'm i missing here?

Comment: try adding the KnownType attributes in your contract.

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas: How do i do that?

Comment: @qamar: i post it on the edit question

Comment: can i see your wsdl document?

Answer (score 4):

[Generics are not supported by WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods).

That being said, I assume you are passing sub-classes of `Type` to `GetEnumerador`. The problem lies in although your service knows about parameters of type `Type` and thus, implicitly creates a `DataContract` for it, it does not know about any other class. This makes serialization fail.

In order to fix it you need to make sub-classes explicit. You have several options

- Customize the serialization by implementing a [`DataContractResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractresolver.aspx)
- Use [`ServiceKnownTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) to annotate your contract which gives two options:

  1. Statically declare the sub-classes by using several `ServiceKnownTypes` annotations, one for each sub-class
  2. Specify a method that will be called dynamically to obtain the types

**EDIT 1**: if you are sure you  are trying to serialize a Type object, take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306/3042204) which shows solution to common problems.

**EDIT 2 (after OP's update)**:

The error indicates that you are passing a `System.RuntimeType` object to `GetEnumerador`. Actually, given that `System.Type` is an abstract, `GetEnumerador` will always receive a sub-class of it.

As I said before, WCF only knows about `Type` which is what you specified in the contract and thus, it yields and error because it does not know how to serialize `System.RuntimeType`. The options I enumerated in the first place still apply. For instance, you can try this:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.RuntimeType))]
public interface IOhmioService
{        
  [OperationContract]
  IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(Type type);       
}
```

Alternative if you are sure that `GetEnumerador` will always receive a `System.RuntimeType` you may do:

```
public interface IOhmioService
{        
  [OperationContract]
  IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(RuntimeType type);       
}
```

All in all, I would advise against serializing `Type` but if for some reason you feel like you must, take a look at [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306/3042204).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure i understand "I assume you are passing sub-classes of Type to GetEnumerador". I use it like this: Clients = this.serviceClient.GetEnumerador(typeof(Clientes));

Comment: @ericpap I've edited the answer after your update, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this code didn't work either. Apparently i can't use System.RuntimeType as parameter because visual studio won't event recognize the type. Also try the  the ServiceKnownType, but also give compiled error (RuntimeType does not exist on system namespace)