# Serializing the Type class in protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is there anything special about serializing the Type class in C#? I am getting the generic:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in   protobuf-net.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> "No serializer defined for type: System.Object"}

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public Type DataType { get; set; }
```

Like so.

Comment: More generally, [Can I serialize a C# Type object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306/can-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-type-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize the fully qualified (or less fully qualified, if appropriate) name of the Type instead. I don't think it is ever appropriate to serialize a static type definition.

Comment: And - speaking as an author or contributor to multiple serializer libraries - I completely agree with you :)

Comment: @MarcGravell what if the client never knows which message it will receive? It would require knowing into which type to deserialize. Using `string` would be too heavy. Would you mind giving an advice on how to customize the serializer so that it would use integer numbers instead of strings?

Comment: @MarcGravell I suppose `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(object)].AddSubType(1, intendedType);` should be the one, but what if `intendedType` is generic?

Comment: nvm solved it via `AfterApplyDefaultBehaviour`