# Send System.Type with WCF using custom serialization?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, deserialization

Can you use custom serialization to send System.Type with WCF?

```
[DataMember]
public Type DataType
```

I was thinking of somehow before it is sent it is converted to string with `.AssemblyQualifiedName` and after receiving it is converted back to Type with `Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName)`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [Can I serialize a C# Type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306/can-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-type-object). even though Type is serializable, you could run into issues as shown in the question

you are better off passing the full name and assembly name across the wire and then recreating the Type from these 2