# Azure Functions not playing well with Json.net and type-name handling

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-functions

I've spent 10+ hours investigating this issue and at this point I feel like it's a bug.

Here's the setup:

I have a function app `MyFunctionApp.csproj` which references a project `MyDataContracts.csproj` that I need to use for serializing/deserializing messages.
 Currently I'm using Json.net for serializing/deserializing.

I can demonstrate that there are problems when trying to deserialize JSON to a type in `MyDataContracts`, even though I can demonstrate that `MyDataContracts.dll` is loaded:

```
// MyClass is from MyDataContracts    
MyClass instance = new MyClass(); // good so far … interesting ...

Type type = instance.GetType();

Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;

log.Info($"Type {type} comes from assembly '{assembly.FullName}', location = '{assembly.Location}'");
// 2018-06-28T14:39:40.630 [Info] Instance of MyDataContracts.MyClass comes from assembly MyDataContracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', location = 'D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\48e7c30a\5fd0f557\assembly\dl3\9681789a\c5d216c9_9f0ed401\MyDataContracts.dll'

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(type, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    ypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
});


log.Info($"Successfully serialized the {type.GetType()}");
// Successfully serialized the System.RuntimeType

log.Info(json);
// "MyDataContracts.MyClass, MyDataContracts, Version=10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

// BOOM! This won't work.
type = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
});

// 2018-06-28T14:39:40.689 [Info] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

// 2018-06-28T14:39:40.689 [Info] Error converting value "MyDataContracts.MyClass, MyDataContracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" to type 'System.Type'. Path '', line 1, position 102.
```

Comment: `Error converting value "MyDataContracts.MyClass, MyDataContracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" to type 'System.Type'. Path '', line 1, position 102.` I think you're trying to cast an _instance_ to a _Type_

Comment: @rickvdbosch "I" am, or Json.net is? By the way, this doesn't happen when I test locally, only when I run in an Azure Functions. It's strange.

Comment: You can find your answer over here: [Can I serialize a C# Type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306/can-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-type-object) Both the first _and_ second answer are interesting reads.