# Trying to Serialize a Type to XML, I Recieve Error "System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level."

Tags: c#, .net

I found the following class in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809872/2226152.

```
// a version of System.Type that can be serialized
[DataContract]
public class SerializableType
{
    public Type type;

    // when serializing, store as a string
    [DataMember]
    string TypeString
    {
        get
        {
            if (type == null)
                return null;
            return type.FullName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                type = null;
            else
            {
                type = Type.GetType(value);
            }
        }
    }

    // constructors
    public SerializableType()
    {
        type = null;
    }
    public SerializableType(Type t)
    {
        type = t;
    }

    // allow SerializableType to implicitly be converted to and from System.Type
    static public implicit operator Type(SerializableType stype)
    {
        return stype.type;
    }
    static public implicit operator SerializableType(Type t)
    {
        return new SerializableType(t);
    }

    // overload the == and != operators
    public static bool operator ==(SerializableType a, SerializableType b)
    {
        // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return a.type == b.type;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(SerializableType a, SerializableType b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
    // we don't need to overload operators between SerializableType and System.Type because we already enabled them to implicitly convert

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return type.GetHashCode();
    }

    // overload the .Equals method
    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to SerializableType return false.
        SerializableType p = obj as SerializableType;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (type == p.type);
    }
    public bool Equals(SerializableType p)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (type == p.type);
    }
}
```

So I am trying to use it using but I have received the following error at runtime.

> InvalidOperationException: System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level. Only public types can be processed.

[Here is a fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ONPvDn) with my Test Program. (Note you will have to copy it into an IDE as Fiddler doesn't have support for System.Runtime.Serialization right now)

For Completeness, my code is also below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<ClassA>();

        var classB = new ClassB();
        var classC = new ClassC();

        list.Add(new ClassA()
        {
            blah = "Test1",
            InterfaceConcreteTypeA = classB.GetType(),
            InterfaceConcreteTypeB = classC.GetType()
        });
        list.Add(new ClassA()
        {
            blah = "Test2",
            InterfaceConcreteTypeA = classB.GetType(),
            InterfaceConcreteTypeB = classC.GetType()
        });
        list.Add(new ClassA()
        {
            blah = "Test3",
            InterfaceConcreteTypeA = classB.GetType(),
            InterfaceConcreteTypeB = classC.GetType()
        });


        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA[]));


        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Test.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, list.ToArray());
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ClassA
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string blah { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public SerializableType InterfaceConcreteTypeA { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public SerializableType InterfaceConcreteTypeB { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassB { }
    public class ClassC { }

    // a version of System.Type that can be serialized
    [DataContract]
    public class SerializableType
    {
        public Type Type;

        // when serializing, store as a string
        [DataMember]
        string TypeString
        {
            get
            {
                if (Type == null)
                    return null;
                return Type.FullName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    Type = null;
                else
                {
                    Type = Type.GetType(value);
                }
            }
        }

        // constructors
        public SerializableType()
        {
            Type = null;
        }
        public SerializableType(Type t)
        {
            Type = t;
        }

        // allow SerializableType to implicitly be converted to and from System.Type
        static public implicit operator Type(SerializableType stype)
        {
            return stype.Type;
        }
        static public implicit operator SerializableType(Type t)
        {
            return new SerializableType(t);
        }

        // overload the == and != operators
        public static bool operator ==(SerializableType a, SerializableType b)
        {
            // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
            if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If one is null, but not both, return false.
            if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match:
            return a.Type == b.Type;
        }
        public static bool operator !=(SerializableType a, SerializableType b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }
        // we don't need to overload operators between SerializableType and System.Type because we already enabled them to implicitly convert

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Type.GetHashCode();
        }

        // overload the .Equals method
        public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
        {
            // If parameter is null return false.
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // If parameter cannot be cast to SerializableType return false.
            SerializableType p = obj as SerializableType;
            if ((System.Object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match:
            return (Type == p.Type);
        }
        public bool Equals(SerializableType p)
        {
            // If parameter is null return false:
            if ((object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match:
            return (Type == p.Type);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: I have resolved the first issue "System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level." however now SerializableType is serialized as an empty tag. See my updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/ONPvDn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a field named 'type' that it's type is `System.Type` :/

That field just holding a reference to a `RuntimeType` instance which causes the error.

`RuntimeType` is not serializable...

Add an `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on it and you will be ok...

Update with result:

[image: Check it]

Comment: I did that, and now it serializes an empty class. 
<InterfaceConcreteTypeA /> 
<InterfaceConcreteTypeB />

Comment: XmlSerializer only going after public fields and properties. If you want to have more control, just implement IXmlSerializable and serialize whatever you would like. in this sample change `string TypeString` to `public string TypeString`